# jsFiddle can't use externall resource like Google Place API?

Tags: google-places-api, jsfiddle

I prepare some small code http://jsfiddle.net/VW9uR/ with External Resource to Google Place API, but the resource doesn't work.
The source is: `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places`
How to add correct resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsfiddle needs a file-extension to determine which type of file should be loaded. Where no file-extension is available add the extension to the QUERY_STRING, e.g.:

```
 http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&.js
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/y939C/

Documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#external-resources

Answer (score 1):

you can add script tag in the html and make it on domready

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

[find it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/VW9uR/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but the External Resource is not for this?