# Google Maps and Fusion Tables Layer Without Drop Shadow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google map set up with a Fusion Table that will highlight only countries that are not APAC.

You can see that the code is working here:
http://russellbits.com/labs/hiex-map/google-fusion-table-simple.html

Bonus points go to anyone who can make it work in JSFiddle. It is the identical code to my web page, but I cannot make it work.
http://jsfiddle.net/ruzel/KTg6P/

Here's the code from the web site:

```
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 104),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk'
        },
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#cfe1f4',
                strokeColor: '#cfe1f4',
                strokeOpacity: '0'
            }
        }, {
            where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('CN','IN','SG','AU','ID','MY','PG','TH')",
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#000000',
                fillOpacity: '0',
                strokeOpacity: '0'
            }
        }],
        map: map
    });
    layer.setMap(map);

    map.mapTypes.set(customMapType);

}

$().ready(function() {
    initialize();
});
```

But here's the big question. There are drop shadows on the polygons that are outlining the countries. I have put polygons on Google maps before and a drop shadow is not something that is on by default. I have searched through the API for any drop shadow variables and cannot find one. So I'm not even sure why this drop shadow is there. Perhaps there is a layer variable?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/KTg6P/8/ (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564221/jsfiddle-cant-use-externall-resource-like-google-place-api/17604383#17604383)

Comment: I'm afraid there is no option to remove these shadows

Comment: I don't actually see any 'drop shadows', what you are actually seeing is that the geometry of the polygons is what they call "simplified" which means reduced number of points for reduction of data overall size constraints. The simplification causes the polygons to not exactly match the actual land boundaries and you are seeing the "overhang". Actually, some spots they overhang, some they underhang.

Comment: What you say makes sense, and I looked closely. But actually, in places where the shape "overhangs" the coast, if you zoom in close, you will still see a drop shadow underneath the overhang (as opposed to the coast). And so far, nothing has worked for removing them. @Dr.Molle may be right.

Comment: The fuion table layer definitely adds a shadow. I am also annoyed by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your fiddle map sample working:

http://jsfiddle.net/helmutgranda/vbjXR/

some of the things were missing are here:

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'> </script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<div id="map"/>
```

In regards to dropshadow, I have to believe there is a setting somewhere that allows you to turn it on and off, altho Google offers rendering of KML without the dropshadow. If it is that important to you, you may be able to take a stab at it with KML (see sample here):

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/layers/layers.html

Interesting enough, I just ran into the following sample which may answer your question:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles

Comment: I have to look more closely at this, for specifics, but your examples clearly illustrate the lack of the drop shadow. Fantastic! And thanks for your time.